# about 600 reputation has disappeared, what did I do wrong?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, reputation

I was just checking SO and found out that my reputation has dropped from about 1200/1300 to 593. What has happened? I didn't do anything special.

Comment: You may have touched yourself in public.

Comment: They should award reputation for that. Not remove it.

Comment: I'm seeing over 1100 rep on your associated account.  http://stackoverflow.com/users/419436/jan

Comment: ahahaha, touché!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, your reputation was recalculated. This could have been initiated by the system after detecting vote fraud, or by a moderator if you've recently had a lot of posts deleted (rep gained from deleted posts are not removed until a recalc).

For a reputation audit, visit https://stackoverflow.com/reputation. You can also trigger a recalc yourself by clicking the button at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: recalculation page shows `** total rep 1139 :)`

Comment: @Jan ... I have never seen this ever happen before. The only scenario which I can think of is a super heavily upvoted post having been deleted, a recalc, and then undeleted, but I don't see a post like that in your profile. I'd go with a one-time glitch, I guess.

Comment: Must be, It just came back.